# Difference between ...state, { } and Object.assign({ }, state, { })

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, redux

Prior ti this question I assumed that `...state, { /* ... */ }` is equivalent es6 syntax of `Object.assign({}, state, { /* ... */ })` but I find more and more repos using both of these in the same file, hence am now slightly confused and think that they serve different purposes. I tried looking up information about this online, but wasn't able to find any clear explanation to how these are different.

Example: https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node/blob/master/app/reducers/topic.js

Comment: The first one is not a valid expression?

Comment: Can you post a link to an example source code that uses these?

Comment: It is equal, just shortcut, There are not refactoring in these repos. Both create new object with mapping

Comment: @Bergi added it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assumed that `...state, { /* ... */ }` is equivalent es6 syntax of `Object.assign({}, state, { /* ... */ })`

Your first syntax is lacking context. In the code you linked, it is used inside an array literal:

```
[...state, { /* ... */ }]
```

where it is a [spread element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) that constructs multiple array elements.

The whole thing does create an *array*, not an object like `Object.assign({}, …)` does.

Spread syntax cannot be used in object literals (in ES6, there are drafts to change this in the future).

Comment: So wouldn't something like { ...state, /* ... */ } be equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You may also see this

```
[...state, Object.assign({}, obj.attribute) ]
```

that's a new attribute placed on the state from an object that is passed to the array, in redux this will usually be an action. This is particularly clever because you first create the object and then look for the element on the array and either create or replace it.